# Set default date when inserting document with time.Time field

Tags: mongodb, go, struct, time, mgo

In `mongoose`(`node.js`) I can define a model schema with a default `Date.now` like so:

```
...
type: Date,
default: Date.now
...
```

How do I achieve the same without having to insert the `time.Time` every time I create a document with `mgo`?

```
type User struct {
    CreatedAt   time.Time `json:"created_at" bson:"created_at"` // Make this field filled automatically with time.Now() every time a document of this `struct` is inserted
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Go you can't define default values for fields, they will always be the [zero-value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) of their type when a new struct value is created (unless you use a [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals) where you can give a different value explicitly).

So one option would be to create a constructor-like function `NewUser()` which would set this field, and use always this function to create new users:

```
func NewUser() *User {
    return &User{
        CreatedAt: time.Now(),
    }
}
```

Of course this can't be forced, and also this will hold the timestamp of the `User` struct value creation and not when it is saved.

Another, better approach is to use a custom marshaling logic.

You can write custom marshaling logic by implementing [`bson.Getter`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#Getter). `GetBSON()` is responsible to provide a value that will actually be saved. We want the same `User` instance to be saved, just its `CreatedAt` field set prior:

```
type User struct {
    CreatedAt time.Time `json:"created_at" bson:"created_at"`
}

func (u *User) GetBSON() (interface{}, error) {
    u.CreatedAt = time.Now()
    type my *User
    return my(u), nil
}
```

Note that a new `my` type is created and returned. The reason for this is to avoid stack overflow. Simply returning a value of type `*User` is bad, because it implements `bson.Getter`, so `GetBSON()` would get called endlessly. The new `my` type does not have this method, so endless "recursion" does not happen (the `type` keyword creates a new type, and it does not "inherit" methods of the underlying type).

Note that this solution will also overwrite (re-set) the `CreatedAt` field) even if you just want to re-save a `User`. So we should add a check whether the `CreatedAt` field is filled, and only set it if it's the zero value:

```
func (u *User) GetBSON() (interface{}, error) {
    if u.CreatedAt.IsZero() {
        u.CreatedAt = time.Now()
    }
    type my *User
    return my(u), nil
}
```

Also see related / similar question: [Accesing MongoDB from Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42342943/accesing-mongodb-from-go/42343810#42343810)