# Accessing MongoDB from Go

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I am accessing MongoDB using Go as follows:

```
var configRes *clientConfigData
err := clientDB.
    C(clientConfigCollection).
    Find(bson.M{}).
    One(&configRes)
if err != nil {
    return nil, errors.Wrap(err, "finding config collection")
}
```

Where

```
type clientConfigData struct {
    SMTPAssoc      int       `bson:"smtp_assoc"`
    PlanType       string    `bson:"plan_type"`
    EndDate        string    `bson:"end_date"`
}
```

Now since `EndDate` in MongoDB is stored as `string` so I declared `EndDate` as `string`. But I need to access this date as Go `Time` in `clientConfigData`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change a value or do a type conversion when marshaling / unmarshaling your values from / to MongoDB, you may do it by implementing a custom marshaling / unmarshaling logic.

You can do this by implementing the [`bson.Getter`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#Getter) and [`bson.Setter`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#Setter) interfaces. Inside these methods, you may do whatever you want to with the values being marshaled / unmarshaled.

Easiest is to extend your `clientConfigData` type with an additional field, one that will be of type [`time.Time`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time), the value you need:

```
type clientConfigData struct {
    SMTPAssoc  int       `bson:"smtp_assoc"`
    PlanType   string    `bson:"plan_type"`
    EndDateStr string    `bson:"end_date"`
    EndDate    time.Time `bson:"-"`
}
```

It has tag value `bson:"-"`, because we don't want this to appear in MongoDB.

And now the custom marshaling / unmarhsaling logic:

```
const endDateLayout = "2006-01-02 15:04:05" // Use your layout here

func (c *clientConfigData) SetBSON(raw bson.Raw) (err error) {
    type my clientConfigData
    if err = raw.Unmarshal((*my)(c)); err != nil {
        return
    }
    c.EndDate, err = time.Parse(endDateLayout, c.EndDateStr)
    return
}

func (c *clientConfigData) GetBSON() (interface{}, error) {
    c.EndDateStr = c.EndDate.Format(endDateLayout)
    type my *clientConfigData
    return my(c), nil
}
```

What happens here is that `SetBSON()` is responsible to "populate" your struct value with the raw value coming from MongoDB, and `GetBSON()` is responsible to provide a value you want to be saved (marshaled).

When loading: `SetBSON()` first unmarshals the value as-is, then properly sets the `EndDate` field (which is of type `time.Time`) from the `string` date value that came from the DB (`EndDateStr`).

When saving: `GetBSON()` first fills the `EndDateStr` field (the one that is saved) from the `EndDate` field, and then simply returns, signaling that it is ok to save.

One thing to note: both `SetBSON()` and `GetBSON()` create a new `my` type inside them. The reason for this is to avoid stack overflow. Simply returning a value of type `clientConfigData` is bad, because we implemented `bson.Getter` and `bson.Setter`, so `SetBSON()` and `GetBSON()` would get called endlessly. The new `my` type does not have these methods, so endless "recursion" does not happen (the `type` keyword creates a new type, and it does not "inherit" methods of the underlying type).

Also see related / similar question: [Set default date when inserting document with time.Time field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41907619/set-default-date-when-inserting-document-with-time-time-field/42344267#42344267)

Comment: so If we didn't implement `bson.Getter` and `bson.Setter` we can simply return the `clienConfigData` right? but in this case we better not. Is this correct?

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense, as adding `GetBSON()` and `SetBSON()` **is** implementing `Getter` and `Setter` (`Getter` and `Setter` are interfaces defining `GetBSON()` and `SetBSON()`). If you don't add those methods, there isn't something to return from.

Comment: Thanks a lot @icza

Comment: @icza I have just one question, how to do the error handling for the error returning from `SetBSON`.

Comment: @SyedQasimRizvi You don't handle it as you are not the one calling `SetBSON()`. It's the `mgo` package that –when loading values from MongoDB– checks if the value implements `Setter`, and if so, it calls its `SetBSON()` to do the unmarshaling. It's the `mgo` package that needs to handle the `error` returned by it, which may be wrapped, logged or returned by the outer function that you called (e.g. `Find().All()` or `Find().One()`).