# Map Mongo _id in two different struct fields in Golang

Tags: mongodb, go, struct, mgo

I am working on a project that uses combination of Go and MongoDB. I am stuck at a place where I have a struct like:

```
type Booking struct {
    // booking fields
    Id                          int                 `json:"_id,omitempty" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    Uid                         int                 `json:"uid,omitempty" bson:"uid,omitempty"`
    IndustryId                  int                 `json:"industry_id,omitempty" bson:"industry_id,omitempty"`
    LocationId                  int                 `json:"location_id,omitempty" bson:"location_id,omitempty"`
    BaseLocationId              int                 `json:"base_location_id,omitempty" bson:"base_location_id,omitempty"`
    }
```

In this struct, the field `Id` is of `int` type. But as we know MongoDB's default id is of `bsonObject` type. Some times, the system generates the default MongoDB id in `Id` field.

To overcome this I have modified the struct like this:

```
type Booking struct {
        // booking fields
        Id                          int                 `json:"_id,omitempty" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
        BsonId              bson.ObjectId       `json:"bson_id" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
        Uid                         int                 `json:"uid,omitempty" bson:"uid,omitempty"`
        IndustryId                  int                 `json:"industry_id,omitempty" bson:"industry_id,omitempty"`
        LocationId                  int                 `json:"location_id,omitempty" bson:"location_id,omitempty"`
        BaseLocationId              int                 `json:"base_location_id,omitempty" bson:"base_location_id,omitempty"`
        }
```

In above struct, I have mapped the same `_id` field in two different struct fields Id (type int) and `BsonId` (type `bson.ObjectId`). I want if id of integer type comes, it maps under `Id` otherwise under `BsonId`.

But this thing is giving following error:

```
Duplicated key '_id' in struct models.Booking
```

How can I implement this type of thing with Go Structs ??

**Update:**

Here is the code I have written for custom marshaling/unmarshaling:

```
func (booking *Booking) SetBSON(raw bson.Raw) (err error) {
    type bsonBooking Booking
    if err = raw.Unmarshal((*bsonBooking)(booking)); err != nil {
        return
    }
    booking.BsonId, err = booking.Id
    return
}

func (booking *Booking) GetBSON() (interface{}, error) {
    booking.Id = Booking.BsonId
    type bsonBooking *Booking
    return bsonBooking(booking), nil
}
```

But this is giving type mismatch error of Id and BsonId fields. What should I do now ?

Answer (score 8):

In your original struct you used this tag for the `Id` field:

```
bson:"_id,omitempty"
```

This means if the value of the `Id` field is `0` ([zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value) for the `int` type), then that field will not be sent to MongoDB. But the `_id` property is mandatory in MongoDB, so in this case the MongoDB server will generate an `ObjectId` for it.

To overcome this, the easiest is to ensure the `Id` will is always non-zero; or if the `0` is a valid id, remove the `omitempty` option from the tag.

If your collection must allow ids of mixed type (`int` and `ObjectId`), then the easiest would be to define the `Id` field with type of `interface{}` so it can accomodate both (actually all) types of key values:

```
Id interface{} `json:"_id,omitempty" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
```

Yes, working with this may be a little more cumbersome (e.g. if you explicitly need the id as `int`, you need to use [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions)), but this will solve your issue.

If you do need 2 id fields, one with `int` type and another with `ObjectId` type, then your only option will be to implement custom BSON marshaling and unmarshaling. This basically means to implement the [`bson.Getter`](https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo/bson#Getter) and / or [`bson.Setter`](https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo/bson#Setter) interfaces (one method for each) on your struct type, in which you may do anything you like to populate your struct or assemble the data to be actually saved / inserted. For details and example, see [Accessing MongoDB from Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42342943/accessing-mongodb-from-go/42343810#42343810).

Here's an example how using custom marshaling it may look like:

Leave out the `Id` and `BsonId` fields from marshaling (using the `bson:"-"` tag), and add a 3rd, "temporary" id field:

```
type Booking struct {
        Id     int           `bson:"-"`
        BsonId bson.ObjectId `bson:"-"`
        TempId interface{}   `bson:"_id"`
        // rest of your fields...
}
```

So whatever id you have in your MongoDB, it will end up in `TempId`, and only this id field will be sent and saved in MongoDB's `_id` property.

Use the `GetBSON()` method to set `TempId` from the other id fields (whichever is set) before your struct value gets saved / inserted, and use `SetBSON()` method to "copy" `TempId`'s value to one of the other id fields based on its dynamic type after the document is retrieved from MongoDB:

```
func (b *Booking) GetBSON() (interface{}, error) {
    if b.Id != 0 {
        b.TempId = b.Id
    } else {
        b.TempId = b.BsonId
    }
    return b, nil
}

func (b *Booking) SetBSON(raw bson.Raw) (err error) {
    if err = raw.Unmarshal(b); err != nil {
        return
    }
    if intId, ok := b.TempId.(int); ok {
        b.Id = intId
    } else bsonId, ok := b.TempId.(bson.ObjectId); ok {
        b.BsonId = bsonId
    } else {
        err = errors.New("invalid or missing id")
    }

    return
}
```

Note: if you dislike the `TempId` field in your `Booking` struct, you may create a copy of `Booking` (e.g. `tempBooking`), and only add `TempId` into that, and use `tempBooking` for marshaling / unmarshaling. You may use embedding (`tempBooking` may embed `Booking`) so you can even avoid repetition.

Comment: So where should I call SetBson() or GetBson() ??

Comment: @Amandeepkaur You don't. It's called by the `mgo` package when values of your struct need to be marshaled or unmarshaled. You just describe how it should be marshaled or unmarshaled, the rest is done by `mgo`.

Comment: You mean I just need to define two functions GetBson() and SetBson() then rest of work will be done by mgo ?

Comment: @Amandeepkaur That's exactly what I'm saying. You are responsible how and what data you marshal and unmarshal in the implementation of those methods.

Comment: I have written the SetBson() and GetBson() functions by taking reference from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42342943/accessing-mongodb-from-go/42343810#42343810. I have written function for Id and BsonId fields. But this is giving me type mismatch error: cannot use booking.BsonId (type bson.ObjectId) as type int in assignment

Comment: @Amandeepkaur First you should try the other tips I gave. If you must go with custom marshaling / unmarshaling: obviously unless you show your code, I won't be able to further assist you with that.

Comment: I can not change the type Id field to interface as it if highly integrated with other modules. So I decided to use custom marshaling/unmarshling. I have updated my post for marshal/unmarshal functions.

Comment: @Amandeepkaur I added example implementations how it can be done.