# How can I assign a null value to date field using mongo go driver instead of Date(-62135596800000)

Tags: mongodb, go, time, mgo

I have two MongoDB servers. From one I receive data using mongo go driver. The received data has one date field which is always `null`. Then in my code I may or may not change it to some other date or leave it as `null` and put the received data to the other server.

The problem is that when I post the data, the time field turns to

> Date(-62135596800000) instead of null.

I have tried to assign `time.Time{}` and the code below didn't solve the problem as well.

```
t, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05Z", "0001-01-01T00:00:01Z")
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
            }
            retrieved[i].SessionEndedDateUTC = t
```

Everytime I get `Date(-62135596800000)` instead of null, even if I retrieve the data and upsert it without modification.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Go [`time.Time`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time) is a struct which cannot have a `nil` value. It has a zero value (which is all struct fields having their zero values), but this zero value corresponds to MongoDB `ISODate("0001-01-01T00:00:00Z")` and not to the MongoDB `null` value.

If your field is of type `time.Time`, you cannot set any value to it to end up MongoDB `null` value.

The simplest solution is to use a field of type pointer to `time.Time` instead, that is `*time.Time`. If you leave or set this field to Go `nil`, it will end up as `null` in MongoDB.

If you can't or don't want to use `*time.Time`, there is still a "workaround": declare 2 fields, one is of your "regular" `time.Time` type, and use a [struct tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858787/what-are-the-uses-for-tags-in-go/30889373#30889373) to exclude this from MongoDB. And add another field of type `*time.Time`, and make this mapped to MongoDB. And write a custom marshaling / unmarshaling logic, which when marshaling would update this extra field based on the original, or would set the original based on the extra when unmarshaling.

This is an example how it could look like:

```
type User struct {
    CreatedAt  time.Time  `bson:"-"`
    PCreatedAt *time.Time `bson:"created"`
}

func (u *User) GetBSON() (interface{}, error) {
    if u.CreatedAt.IsZero() {
        u.PCreatedAt = nil
    } else {
        u.PCreatedAt = &u.CreatedAt
    }
    return u, nil
}

func (u *User) SetBSON(raw bson.Raw) (err error) {
    if err = raw.Unmarshal(u); err != nil {
        return
    }
    if u.PCreatedAt == nil {
        u.CreatedAt = time.Time{}
    } else {
        u.CreatedAt = *u.PCreatedAt
    }
    return
}
```

**Explanation:**

`User.CreatedAt` holds the `time.Time` value which you can work with (read / write). This field is excluded from MongoDB.

There is a pointer `User.PCreatedAt` field which is mapped to the `created` property in MongoDB.

When a `User` is marshaled (saved to MongoDB), `GetBSON()` is called. If `CreatedAt` is the zero value, sets `PCreatedAt` to `nil` which will end up as `null` in MongoDB. Else sets / uses the non-zero timestamp.

When a `User` is unmarshaled (loaded from MongoDB), `SetBSON()` is called. This checks if `PCreatedAt` is `nil` (which corresponds to MongoDB `null`), and if so, sets `CreatedAt` to its zero value. Else uses the timestamp retrieved from MongoDB.

Related / similar questions:

[Set default date when inserting document with time.Time field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41907619/set-default-date-when-inserting-document-with-time-time-field/42344267#42344267)

[Accesing MongoDB from Go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42342943/accesing-mongodb-from-go/42343810#42343810)

Comment: Thanks so much. I won't be doing this exactly how you showed me, but your answer gave me a very good idea how to solve this. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

mongodb doc

Behavior

Internally, Date objects are stored as a 64 bit integer representing the number of milliseconds since the Unix epoch (Jan 1, 1970), which results in a representable date range of about 290 millions years into the past and future

see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Date/

Comment: I have read the documentation before. It is not a problem with mongodb. The probloem was with the Go language, because it automatically sets a Date value o a null field. I had to work it out with pointers very similar how icza suggested. Still thanks