# How to set default value when fetching data from mongodb

Tags: mongodb, go

I've used *go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo* package to fetch data from MongoDB to my Go application.
To define data structure I've something like this:

```
type Data struct {
    Type    string    `bson:"type,omitempty"`
}
```

Is there any way to define default value if "type" property doesn't exists in MongoDB document?
If no, what's the correct way?

Comment: You may use a custom unmarshaler, see [Set default date when inserting document with time.Time field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41907619/set-default-date-when-inserting-document-with-time-time-field/42344267#42344267)

Answer (score 0):

You can make your struct unexported, and make an exported constructor function like `NewData()` where you initialise your struct.

```
type data struct {
    Type    string    `bson:"type,omitempty"`
}

func NewData() data {
    return data{Type: "SampleType"}
}
```

Now, invoke `NewData()` before fetching from MongoDb, and the default values will be there for which Mongo doesn't send the value.